# How do I connect a webapp and an android app with firebase?

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, mediastore

I have been trying to learn how to create an app that allows people to upload images via the web or android.

I know that Android uses content providers to implement a mechanism for the sharing of data between applications. More specifically, Android uses the MediaStore API to make use of this functionality. However, that is limited to other Android devices.

I was wondering how I would go about connecting a web app made using reactjs to an Android app preferably using firebase. However, if it isn't possible in firebase that would be okay too,

I am a beginner in web app development, so I am not particularly sure about how the software's architecture will look like.

I have been struggling to find an updated concise solution online. Can anyone point me in the right direction and if not point me to some resources that will guide me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach/configure both of your application to use same database and storage bucket in firebase[image]

As you can see I connected my android application as well as web administration application to same firebase project.[image]

As you can see there is an add app option in firebase console where you can select platform. Register both of your application on same project and thats it.